# Why does Eclipse think that my XML syntax is wrong?

Tags: xml, eclipse, maven, syntax

I use maven for web automation and whenever I add my dependencies, Eclipse keeps saying that there's something wrong with my syntax. This only happens in XML codes and the common problem it seems to pick up is the missing ending tag as such in the pic.

[image]

My programs still run perfectly despite it thinking there's a syntax error but it's just annoying to see those red ugly lines on my code. Is there any fix to this?


XML file: pastebin.com/N8wRjdhB

Comment: Please, expand the `<dependency>` nodes...

Comment: Here is the entire xml file pastebin.com/N8wRjdhB

Comment: Please, just add it to the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem by cutting all the dependency blocks then pasting it to notepad then copying it back in Eclipse. Idk why it suddenly thinks that my syntax is now correct when there weren't any changes made at all.

Comment: Probably tag names string included some invisible signs.

Answer (score 0):

Because your XML syntax is wrong :)
Each tag should be closed while you have opened 5 dependency tags but did not close them.
It should be something like this:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.141.59</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>7.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
      
        ------------
</dependencies>
```

each tag opened like this `<dependency>` and after that closed like this `</dependency>`
The same about all the sub-tags `<groupId>org.testng</groupId>` - tag is opened `<groupId>` and after that closed `</groupId>`

***UPD***
Well, after you presented us the XML file it indeed looks correct.
So, maybe there are some characters in tag opening are not matching the string in the tag closing? Like some of them in English and others in some other language?

Comment: Nah the dependency closing tags are there. I just copy and paste them off from the maven repository so those cant be wrong, right?

Comment: dependency closing tag is present, it's just that it's not expanded

Comment: Can you show the actual XML file content?

Comment: Here is the entire xml file https://pastebin.com/N8wRjdhB